# Deploy image using openshift origin UI

Tags: openshift, docker-registry, openshift-origin

Working with origin v1.5.1

I want to deploy images from external docker registry.

I have docker registry configured to work with ssl and when trying to deploy with *oc new-app* command i am able to.

However when i am trying to deploy from UI i am getting this error:
**Internal error occurred: Get https://myregistry.corp.dddd.com:6000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

Anyone faced it before?

thanks

Comment: Can you confirm you are using a self signed certificate with your external docker registry? Are you also using login credentials for the external docker registry as well?

Comment: And are you using the ``--insecure-registry`` flag when running ``oc new-app`` if deploying the image from the command line?

Comment: i am using self signed certificate from my external docker registry.  didnt understand what you mean with "login credentials for the external docker registry" .    regarding --insecure-registry  , i dont want to use this flag since i want to run in secured mode